# button.onclick does'nt work when websocket server is online

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, onclick, event-listener

Ok so this is weird, I have a frontend js file and a html file :

```js
const conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const send = document.querySelector('#send');
const text = document.querySelector('#text');

conn.onopen = () => {
  console.log('connetion open');
  conn.send('heyya');
}

conn.onmessage = message => main.innerHTML += message.data;

conn.onerror = error => console.log('web socket not available');

send.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('send');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <input type="text" name="" id="text">
    <button id="send">Send</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

whenever the websocket is up and running, clicking on send button does nothing and variable send doesn't seem to be referring to the send button in html.
But whenever websocket is offline send button is working as expected.

Is it some typo or any other mistake by me or something with JS ?

Answer (score 2):

```
conn.onmessage = message => main.innerHTML += message.data;
```

is equal to

```
main.innerHTML = main.innerHTML + message.data
```

Will destroy everything inside and recreate it. When this happens the event bindings are gone. You should use a method like [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or you can add a new element to inject new messages into, like:

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <input type="text" name="" id="text">
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: wait how ? that line is adding more html, not rewriting, right ?

Comment: @me.nkr DOM doesn't work like a string, it is collection of objects. When you change `innerHTML` all child objects are destroyed and re-created based on the new HTML string.

Comment: @me.nkr even if it was a string manipulation,  *Javascript String is immutable*, there is no way to modify a string without creating a new one and assigning a reference to it

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I noticed you need to improve is that you should:-
`conn.send(JSON.stringify('heyya'))`
while sending data on WebSocket.

And do the same while receiving:-
`JSON.parse(message)`, and then use the "message" the way you want to.

Comment: since it's just string, this might be enough.